# How I get istio object status(e.g virtualservice running status) from kubernetes API or other ways?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

As the title, I want to get the istio object running status from the kubernetes platform but the kubernetes API not support CRS object's status, so hope someone help me, give me the solution, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You might not have permissions to update a custom resource's `status`, but you can get it by doing a `GET` API call on the object. The `GET` API call will return the complete object, along with the status part.

Alternatively, you can also see the status by doing a `kubectl get virtualservice -o="jsonpath={.status}"`.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller/blob/499fb3ff94b9068498a9474e813cd5526a3821f0/controller.go#L251) is an example on how to use the API to issue a `GET` API call on a custom resource.